# General question about SSIS Solution/Projects

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ssis

1. I copied a folder containing a *.sln, *.dtproj and many *.dtsx files to my Desktop
2. I opened up the solution from my DESKTOP and saw that the packages within the opened project still pointed to the packages at their original location, not the desktop location that I copied them to.

Opening up the dtproj file in notepad, I see that the references to the packages in the project are not relative, but fully qualified and set to the original location.

Is this normaL? Was something done diefferently when the packages were originally added such that the references were stored as fully qualified instead of relative? This sure seems like undesirable behavior and I generally thought that Visual Studio uses relative references in a proj file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it has been identified as a bug - [SSIS files should not store absolute paths](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/307492/ssis-files-should-not-store-absolute-paths).

Did you happen to pull your project files from source control?

Comment: No, from a server share folder.

Comment: Very strange. I've only been able to find articles for packages using absolute paths for objects *within* the package, or solutions using absolute paths when moved from source control. But not exactly what your situation is. Will keep hunting as now I'm intrigued!

Comment: After I discovered that my project file contained absolute paths to each of the packages in the project, I updated the path to a corrected  local but still absolute path. Later, I decided to go back and change it to a relative path and I saw that it was already a relative path--perhaps "Saving All" corrected the isses? I' at a lost. But for now on, I'll be watching my proj file for odd behavior.